# Webdriver crashing with selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: newSession

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

OS: El Capitan Version `10.11.4 (15E65)`

Python Version: `2.7.14`

Selenium Version: **`selenium=3.14.1`**

Browser: **Mozilla Firefox 62.0**

**Expected Behavior -**

Open a firefox browser and do some steps - parsing & scraping a website.

**Actual Behavior -**

*Crashing with a log :*

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()


Traceback (most recent call last):


File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/utilisateur/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
keep_alive=True)File "/Users/utilisateur/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
File "/Users/utilisateur/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/Users/utilisateur/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Users/utilisateur/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/utilisateur/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: newSession
```

Actually, it used to work correctly, untill it randomly stopped. I have already checked Firefox just to be sure that it is a supported versions.
Also, I did recheck that I still have a required Selenium version, as in [this](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html) . So now, as a beginner in python, I have to say that I found myself faced with a wall of mist.

Has anyone faced this issue before and has a possible solution ?
(P.S. I couldnt find an anwser in related topics already published on Stackoverflow )

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem right now, this was happen with me however I was using chrome, after update from 62 to 71 solved my problem. Try to update to latest version of Firefox.

Selenium version: 3.5
Chrome Version: 71
Python version: 3.7

Comment: Hello SdxaDev, thanks for your advice. 
I finally went for something more drastic, I uninstall and reinstall Firefox. I would not be able to tell you why, since I reinstall the same version, but it works now.